# Erro ao importar DLL

Tags: c#, dll, activex

Tenho uma DLL feita em C#. Ao importar ela para ser usada em outro computador, eu encontro a classe. Contudo, os métodos dela não estão publicados;

Segue meu código:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace PortalRH.DLL
{
[ComVisible(true), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),
Guid("00AC4F7E-71B0-4BC7-AD8E-1175CD88457A")]
public class Criptografia 
{
    private string chave = "chave";
    public Criptografia(){}


    // Essa seqüência constante é usada como um valor "salt" para as chamadas de função PasswordDeriveBytes .
    // Este tamanho da IV (em bytes) devem = (KeySize / 8). KeySize padrão é 256, portanto, a IV deve ser
    // 32 bytes de comprimento. Usando uma seqüência de 16 caracteres aqui nos dá 32 bytes quando convertido para um array de bytes.
    private static readonly byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("tu89geji340t89u2");

    // Esta constante é utilizado para determinar o tamanho da chave do algoritmo de encriptação.
    private const int keysize = 256;

    public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string passPhrase)
    {
        byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        using (PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null))
        {
            byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
            using (RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes))
                {
                    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                            byte[] cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                            return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string cipherText, string passPhrase)
    {
        byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        using (PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null))
        {
            byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
            using (RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes))
                {
                    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes))
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                        {
                            byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
                            int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Esta DLL foi enviada para outro programador, para utilizar os métodos dela. Porém ele não conseguiu visualizar os métodos da mesma.

Eu verifiquei, e os métodos não aparecem no Arquivo **.TLB** que ele está usando.

Comment: E que esta DLL foi enviada para outro programador, para utilizar os métodos dela. Porém ele não conseguiu visualizar os métodos da mesma.

Comment: E no Objecto Browser do VB, não aparece os métodos. Gostaria de saber se possuo algum erro no código, para ele n conseguir visualizar os métodos la

Comment: Entendi. O seu colega adicionou todas as referências no projeto dele? Se não me engano ele terá que adicionar a referência da sua DLL e depois adicionar o namespace no projeto.

Comment: Sim, ele não está conseguindo visualizar os métodos nem no Object Browser do VB

Comment: Porém, no meu computador, funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Algum problema ou alguma ele não fez. Se fosse o código, você teria problemas também, concorda? Ainda acho acho que falta algum using para ele fazer só vendo o código e a forma como ele está trampando. Tem como postar o código dele, as chamadas dele e etc...?

Comment: Ele não está conseguindo visualizar os métodos, nem utilizando o Object Browser do VB. Não chegou a implementar código.

Comment: Verifiquei, e os métodos não aparecem no Arquivo.TLB, que ele está usando. No .DDL aparecem todos os métodos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"TLB"? Então ele está tentando consumir sua DLL como um componente ActiveX.

O problema é que o **COM** não suporta métodos estáticos e quando seu colega cria o proxy para a sua DLL os métodos estáticos não são incluídos no proxy.

Retire a palavra chave **static** da declaração dos seus métodos e o seu colega poderá consumi-los como um objeto ActiveX.

Sugestão: se você não quiser refatorar agora todo o seu próprio código que consome estes métodos, em vez de retirar o **static**, declare novos métodos de instância que consumam estes métodos estáticos. Mais ou menos assim:

```
public class Criptografia 
{
    public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string passPhrase)
    { // ... este é o seu método original
        ...
    }

    public string _Encrypt(string plainText, string passPhrase)
    { // ... este é o novo método, que consome o original.
      // ... é este novo método que o seu colega vai consumir
        return Criptografia.Encrypt(plainText, passPhrase);
    }
    ...
}
```

É claro que provavelmente seu código pode ficar mais bacana que isso e esta é apenas uma sugestão para ser usada durante os testes.

Comment: Eu retirei o método static e rodei um teste. O teste funcionou perfeitamente( com o resultado esperado), porém, ao fazer o build do projeto, recebo o seguinte erro: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property.
Acusa a falta do static. Isso me ocasionará problemas, ou posso deixar assim?

Comment: @RenilsonAndrade Mostre a linha de código que está causando este erro.

Comment: E quando eu chamo o método( onde retirei o atributo statico)
      Console.WriteLine("Sua string criptografada e: ");
            string contrato = Criptografia.Encrypt(text, chave);
            Console.WriteLine(contrato);
            Console.WriteLine("");

Comment: @RenilsonAndrade Ôps! Os nomes dos métodos estavam iguais. Editei minha resposta adicionando um "underline" no começo do nome de um dos métodos.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado