# Metodo static em Interface

Tags: c#, visual-basic-6, interface, dll

Possuo uma classe para criptografar dados. Porém ela será utilizada como uma DLL, e para isso necessito criar uma interface para mostrar os métodos( testei sem a interface e não funcionou). Porém, ela contém 2 métodos estáticos, e estou recebendo erro por isso. Existe uma forma de fazer essa interface ou converter minha classe para não utilizar mais o static?

Segue meu código:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace PortalRH.DLL
{
[ComVisible(true), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),
Guid("00AC4F7E-71B0-4BC7-AD8E-1175CD88457A")]
public class Criptografia 
{
private string chave = "chave";
public Criptografia(){}


// Essa seqüência constante é usada como um valor "salt" para as chamadas de função PasswordDeriveBytes .
// Este tamanho da IV (em bytes) devem = (KeySize / 8). KeySize padrão é 256, portanto, a IV deve ser
// 32 bytes de comprimento. Usando uma seqüência de 16 caracteres aqui nos dá 32 bytes quando convertido para um array de bytes.
private static readonly byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("tu89geji340t89u2");

// Esta constante é utilizado para determinar o tamanho da chave do algoritmo de encriptação.
private const int keysize = 256;

public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string passPhrase)
{
    byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
    using (PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null))
    {
        byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
        using (RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes))
            {
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                        byte[] cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                        return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static string Decrypt(string cipherText, string passPhrase)
{
    byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
    using (PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null))
    {
        byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
        using (RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes))
            {
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
                        int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Interface:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace PortalRH.DLL
{
[Guid("16E2B6C1-1CC2-4B71-BE4E-9F6DF103AA3E")]
public interface ICriptografia
{


    string Encrypt(string str);
    string Decrypt(string str);

}
```

}

Segue o erro retornado:

```
> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 
> 'PortalRH.DLL.Criptografia.Decrypt(string, string)'
```

Comment: Post o erro retornado.

Comment: @Jota Editei com o erro retornado

Comment: Onde está sua interface?

Comment: Adicionei a interface agora

Answer (score 3, accepted):

COM não suporta métodos estáticos, isso é uma regra e não existe o que fazer.

Você vai ter que modificar sua classe para que todos os métodos sejam membros da instância, ou no mínimo incluir métodos não estáticos que chamem os métodos estáticos, e então estes métodos não estáticos é que devem ser incluídos na sua interface.

Comment: Teria como explicar um pouco mais, de como eu faço isso?

Comment: @RenilsonAndrade Explicado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/47450/14584

Comment: Desculpe, nem havia olhado. Obrigado